# need to commit (or rollback) after encountering an error in SELECT statements

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

when encountering an error in `SELECT` statements, apparently *TRANSACTION* stays open.

make connection with psycopg:

```py
# ...
connection.autocommit = False
cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=DictCursor)
```

select the non-exists table:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "non_exists_table"') # a incorrect query
```

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "non_exists_table" does not exist
```

then execute another query:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "exists_table"') # this is a correct query
```

```
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

why?

Does `psycopg2` open a *TRANSACTION* for all `execute()`? even `SELECT`?!!

Is it possible to avoid start *TRANSACTION* in select query?

Comment: A select query will open a trasnaction by default - see [the rtansaction control docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control).  If you set `autocommit = True` on the connection it won't request a rollback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Postgres in a web app: "transaction aborted" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209169/using-postgres-in-a-web-app-transaction-aborted-errors)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The answer is almost the same, but the question is different, I didn't know that psycopg opens a transaction for select queries. My question is more about psycopg and also select query.

Comment: @PersianMan there will be a transaction for any query (not just select queries). The question being different doesn't matter the answer is the same, which is why the comment says "Does this _answer_ your question?"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat When the question is not the same, how to search for the question? Asking questions is harder than searching, I always search a lot and if I can't find it, I ask. I only asked 15 questions in 6 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tanks from [@snakecharmerb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5320906/snakecharmerb) for comment*

by [this](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control) reference:

> By default, the first time a command is sent to the database (using one of the cursors created by the connection), a new transaction is created.

> Should any command fail, the transaction will be aborted and no further command will be executed until a call to the rollback() method.

solution1:

```
connection.autocommit = True
```

solution2:

```
with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL)
```

if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back.

**Unlike file objects or other resources, exiting the connection’s with block doesn’t close the connection, but only the transaction associated to it.**